# Fast evaluation of trigonometric polynomials

Tags: algorithms, numerics, approximation, fourier-transform, signal-processing

Suppose you have a trigonometric polynomial of the form
\begin{equation*}
x(t) = \sum_{k = 0}^N a_k \cos(2 \pi k f_0 t).
\end{equation*}
Using [Clenshaw algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clenshaw_algorithm), one can evaluate this polynomial in $O(N)$, just as an ordinary polynomial via Horner's rule. Now:

1. Is it possible to evaluate $x(t)$ in less than $O(N)$ in general? Also negative or partial results are appreciated.
2. What if $x(t)$ has a particular form? For example, if $a_k = \frac{(-1)^k}{k}$, $x(t)$ is the truncated Fourier series of a sawtooth wave.
3. In case of negative answer, is there at least some fast algorithm that approximates $x(t)$?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: While trig polynomials are often useful to assess qualitative properties, they are rarely useful to actually *evaluate* the function. This goes to your point (2). It is almost always better to think about what you know about the coefficients $a_k$ and whether there is a representation better suited for numerical evaluation.

Comment: In the general case, I do not know anything else on the coefficients. If this is too hard, a result on the classical waveforms (sawtooth, square, triangle, ...) would also be interesting. Notice that $x(t)$ is the real part of $\tilde x(t) = \sum_{k = 0}^N a_k e^{2 \pi i k f_0 t}$, so in some sense my problem is a particular case of (ordinary) polynomial evaluation.

Comment: You only get that average FFT speed for multi-point evaluations of $N$ or more values. If the evaluation points do not form an arithmetic progression, one might get numerical instability.

Comment: @Lutz Lehmann can you elaborate more?

Comment: You have to read all the coefficients, so it's at least O(N).

Comment: @user14717 you're right. I also realized that my observation on FFT was wrong, so I edited the first question. It's still interesting to look at questions 2) and 3).

Comment: 2) is still confusing, especially since the list of $a_k$s is assumed finite in the setup. So if the list is finite, then you have to do pattern detection and then extrapolate assume that pattern continues no?

Comment: No, I was really looking at the truncated series, I don't want to guess the "missing terms" of a Fouries series. Regarding the first question, I forgot to say that preprocessing of the coefficients is allowed, so there might be a way to get a better algorithm that does not need $O(N)$ reads.